# Get variable from child class variable stored in parent class variable

Tags: java

How to access child class variables? Is it necessary to convert object?

```
public class A {
    int first;
}

public class B extends A{
    int second;
}

public void doTheMagic(){
    B variableB = new B();
    A variableA = variableB;
    variableA.second; //-> second is unknown;
}
```

Comment: you classes `a` and `b` have no relation. there is no parent/child.... forgot `extends`?

Comment: What is the relation between A and B? Do they inherit or extent one another?

Comment: Where (in what class) is `doTheMagic()`?

Comment: Accessing child class property/function from Parent is not possible unless you typecast it to the child class.

Answer (score 0):

While you can assign `varibaleB` to type `A` (since `B` inherits from `A`), `A` does not have a class member called `second`.

Of course, you know that it is of type `B`, so you can cast it:

```
B variableB = new B();
A variableA = variableB;
((B)variableA).second;
```

**To clarify:** You can only access the class members of the concrete type, not its subclasses.

Comment: Is it possible to do it dynamically In case there is more subclasses? I have list of objects. Like ((SOME_DYNAMIC_MAGIC)variableA).second;

Comment: I guess i will need more details to answer that, you can use generics or programm against an interface, which declares a contract that all implememntations must meet.